# Converting DEM to Floating Point Raster (FLT) using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, vectorization

I am looking to convert a .DEM exported from AutoCad to a floating point raster file type (.FLT) utilizing QGIS to implement in [HEC-RAS Mapper](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-ras/features.aspx).

This is accomplished easily in Arc using the Raster>Float option.  Referencing [ESRI Supported Formats](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Supported_raster_dataset_file_formats/009t0000000q000000/GUID-4E36E441-55EE-496A-9F8E-DCBD2FE72A9F/) it does not appear the .FLT format is proprietary. It does mention  "Write—Only via Raster To Float tool, or developer code" which could suggest that it could be incorporated into QGIS.  Although, the QGIS Raster>Translate does not offer the .FLT format.

Is there open-source workaround to convering DEM to .FLT?

Comment: Use Raster::Translate and specify the output type. What format is it currently in? CAD is usually XYZ which isn't the best format - usually it's not gridded like translate likes.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson, I have the same problem and tried this solution. But couldn't find the option in "translate" to save as Floating Point (*.flt).

Comment: Have a read of http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000422.shtml.... it appears to be a bil file with different wording in the header. Read also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness to find the default endianness of your system... on a PC the data will be LSB first. Do you have any scripting/programming experience? This wouldn't be hard to do in python/C#/C++ or almost any language that supports GDAL @H.Wiener.

Answer (score 3):

The Esri FLT data format stores its data identically to an Esri BIL file, which GDAL [does support](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html):

```
GDAL_Translate -of EHdr -ot Float32 ....
```

Then all you need to do is change the extension from bil to flt and edit the header - the keywords are different.. for example:

```
BYTEORDER      I
LAYOUT         BIL
NROWS          1004
NCOLS          1002
NBANDS         1
NBITS          32
BANDROWBYTES   4008
TOTALROWBYTES  4008
PIXELTYPE      FLOAT
ULXMAP         478000.5
ULYMAP         6937001.5
XDIM           1
YDIM           1
NODATA         -9999
```

is what is in the header from GDAL translate, which needs to be changed to:

```
ncols        1002
nrows        1004
xllcorner    478000.000000000000
yllcorner    6935998.000000000000
cellsize     1.000000000000
NODATA_value  -9999
BYTEORDER    LSBFIRST
```

for a FLT file... easy as!

First change NODATA to NODATA_VALUE (if not already, both keywords are supported by Esri BIL), `BYTEORDER` keyword changes from `I` (Intel) to `LSBFIRST` - assuming Intel, only one cellsize is supported so get rid of `XDIM, YDIM` and replace with `CELLSIZE` change `ULXMAP` to `XLLCENTER` and then it gets tricky.. BIL is *upper* left referenced but FLT is *lower* left referenced so you need to reduce the reference by `NROWS * CELLSIZE` to obtain `YLLCENTER`.

You should be able to validate your results in QGIS (I used 2.6 (Brighton)) by drag-n-drop the .flt file into the window.